# How to prevent errors from reaching the console?

Tags: javascript

... in Safari

I've tried both preventDefault and stopPropagation but neither works.

```
        window.addEventListener("error", function (event) {
            if ( event.target.tagName === 'IMG' ) {
                event.target.src = 'fake_path';
                // event.preventDefault();
                // event.stopPropagation();
            }
        }, true);
```

Note that I have capture set to true.  Maybe this has something to do with it.

Here is an example of the error: (there is a little red icon to the left of it with an exclamation point )

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

Comment: It's possible that it can't be done at all. Why do you want to do this, what is your use case?

Comment: You can't catch & hide that error. It's a feature of the developer tools.

Comment: I could use try/throw/catch...that would work.

Comment: A resource loading error is a network error, not a JavaScript error, and therefore cannot be caught by JavaScript.

Comment: @Smurfette: how would you do that for 404s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error is part of the dev tools and not JavaScript natively. You can capture errors using `window.onerror`. This post goes into more detail on error capture.

http://mattsnider.com/window-onerror-event/

Comment: The OP obviously understands event errors.  However browsers behave differently after a capture.  Some report the error in the console, some do not.